# Length of two dimensional array in Javascript/Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a two dimensional array in a Google apps script

```
data = [[1, 2], [3, 4]];
```

Trying to get the length of data returns "Undefined". Why is that?

```
Logger.log(data.length) // Outputs "Undefined"
```

**Update (full code):**

```
data = sheet.getSheetValues(1, 1, 10, 2);
Logger.log("readSpreadSheet");
Logger.log(data);
Logger.log(data.length);
```

**Log:**

```
[14-02-10 15:05:05:592 CET] readSpreadSheet
[14-02-10 15:05:05:592 CET] [[tt0062622, 10.0], [tt0066921, 10.0], [tt0094721, 8.0], [tt0445934, 10.0], [tt0784972, 7.0], [tt1136608, 1.0], [tt0119116, 10.0],     [tt1195478, 7.0], [tt2234155, 1.0], [tt1675434, 9.0]]
[14-02-10 15:05:05:592 CET] undefined
```

Comment: Are you sure your variable in scope? Show us the rest of the code.

Comment: Print out the value of data.

Comment: Updated. This is how it's supposed to work in JS right? Maybe it's a Google AS bug :/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You made a typo in your code...
you wrote `lenght` instead of `length`

code :

```
data = sheet.getSheetValues(1, 1, 10, 2);
Logger.log("readSpreadSheet");
Logger.log(data);
Logger.log(data.length);
```

log:

```
data.length = 10
```

Comment: Doh! I mean I typed it twice just to make sure and think I event used auto-complete, apparently not. Well spotted!

Comment: connections between fingers and brain are sometimes a bit difficult... I certainly know that issue ;-) - thx for upvote